# How to fix #Value! Error in my Excel Code

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Im setting up a new formula in Excel and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I could also be going about doing this with the wrong formula, but dont know a better way of doing this. With my if statement im getting a #Value! output after a few cells.

I have a long if statement that I am trying to output a list based on a range of cells. If 1 is present output product number else move on to if 2 is present... so on and so forth. The issue is I want a singular formula for all my cells without it repeating. So I added an and statement to them saying if 1 is present and not listed in any of the cells before then 1 else if 2 is present and not listed in any of the cells above. Everything works fine for the first 3 cells then I get a #Value! output on the forth cell and dont know what to do.

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF($B$6:$B$10,"PTFE")>0,NOT($J$3:J5=Mats!B$5)),Mats!B$5,
IF(AND(COUNTIF($B$6:$B$10,"Polyimide")>0,NOT($J$3:J5=Mats!B$9)), Mats!B$9,
IF(AND($B$4 < 0.02,COUNTIF($B$6:$B$10,"DPIT")>0,NOT($J$3:J5=Mats!B$6)),Mats!B$6,
IF(AND($B$4>0.02,COUNTIF($B8:$B12,"DPIT")>0,NOT($J$3:J5=Mats!B$7)),Mats!B$7,
IF(AND(COUNTIF($B$6:$B$10,"Pebax")>0,COUNTIF($C$6:$C$10,"72D")>0,NOT($J$3:J5=Mats!B$10)),Mats!B$10,
IF(AND(COUNTIF($B$6:$B$10,"Pebax")>0,COUNTIF($C$6:$C$10,"70D")>0,NOT($J$3:J5=Mats!B$11)),Mats!B$11,
IF(AND(COUNTIF($B$6:$B$10,"Pebax")>0,COUNTIF($C$6:$C$10,"63D")>0,NOT($J$3:J5=Mats!B$12)),Mats!B$12,
IF(AND(COUNTIF($B$6:$B$10,"Pebax")>0,COUNTIF($C$6:$C$10,"55D")>0,NOT($J$3:J5=Mats!B$13)),Mats!B$13,
IF(AND(COUNTIF($B$6:$B$10,"Teco")>0,COUNTIF($C$6:$C$10,"93A")>0,NOT($J$3:J5=Mats!B$17)),Mats!B$17,
IF(AND(COUNTIF($B$6:$B$10,"Teco")>0,COUNTIF($C$6:$C$10,"80A")>0,NOT($J$3:J5=Mats!B$18)),Mats!B$18,
IF(AND(COUNTIF($B$6:$B$10,"Teco")>0,COUNTIF($C$6:$C$10,"60D")>0,NOT($J$3:J5=Mats!B$19)),Mats!B$19,0)))))))))))
```

Comment: Woah - take a step back, can you not add a helper column or some other information that would help whittle down that formula? Debugging that is not going to be fun. (Can you not use `VLOOKUP()` for part of it?)

Comment: Wow! As a rule of thumb, any formula longer than 80 characters needs to be broken up. Yes, certainly a case for a lookup table here.

Comment: Ok I didn't know about this function I will break up everything and see if that helps

Comment: @Bathsheba So I separated all the if statements into their own table. That table has blanks if the key word is not present and the part number if the key word is present now how do I make a table in the original page where it prints out only part numbers and no spaces in between them

Comment: I think that’s best asked as a separate question, with a few cells by way of an example. There are some tricks depending on the data.

Answer (score -1):

You should make sure that the you remove any spaces in the function and look out for use of special characters if any. If there are any more problems then you can look it up [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/how-to-correct-a-value-error-15e1b616-fbf2-4147-9c0b-0a11a20e409e).

Good luck!